# Robotframework : how to get all keys of JSON as list

Tags: python-3.x, api, automation, robotframework

Can someone explain me how to get all keys of JSON as list in robot framework?

example:

```
{
   "api": "rest",
   "framework": "robot-framework"
}
```

I have to get list of properties (api,framework)

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the JSON string to a dictionary, and then call the `keys` method on the dictionary. For the latter you can use the built-in keyword [call method](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Call%20Method), or use [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax).

Example:

```
*** Variables ***
${json_string} 
    ...   {
    ...       "api": "rest",
    ...       "framework": "robot-framework"
    ...   }

*** Test cases ***
Example

    # convert the JSON to a python object
    ${json}=    evaluate    json.loads($json_string)    json

    # get the keys using `call method`
    ${keys}=  call method  ${json}  keys
    should contain  ${keys}  api
    should contain  ${keys}  framework    

    # get the keys using extended variable syntax
    ${keys}=  set variable   ${json.keys()}
    should contain  ${keys}  api
    should contain  ${keys}  framework
```

Comment: Thank a lot.. what i need, is camparing all keys of two json.
I have two long json, and i need to campare the keys of the two jsons that should be equal

Comment: @saf: that wasn't part of your original question. You asked how to get the keys, this shows  how to get the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, there is a Get Dictionary Keys keyword in the Collections library that I use. It does exactly what you're after:

```
${json} =    Convert To Dictionary    ${json}
${list} =    Get Dictionary Keys    ${json}

Log    ${list}    #This should now give you api and framework
```